# Boot from USB in macbook pro mid 2012

Tags: macos, mac, startup, disk-utility

I have removed everything from my macbook pro. Now, how can choose USB as a startup disk? I tried using `option`    `"SHIFT"` keys also `cmd+R`. Nothing is working. How can I solve it? I am using Mid 2012 Macbook Pro and that usb is Ubuntu installer. [Btw, I am not interested to install Ubuntu in mac.]

Comment: how did you make your bootable ubuntu usb ?

Answer (score 1):

The 'option' key at startup will give you the option of selecting another startup disk. The problem may be that your USB stick is not considered a valid startup option.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to test if it boots from any other USB bootable source? To test if it's your mac or your Ubuntu installer that is the problem.